# How to convert *.mha file to *.nii file in Python (without using MedPy) or C?

Tags: python, c++, image-processing

I want to process `*.mha` file in `Python`. But it requires the `MedPy` package which depends on `ITK` package. I am currently having problems installing `ITK` package. I was thinking of whether there is a way to convert `*.mha` file to `*.nii` file (using some other way, may be `C++`) because I can then use `Python` to read `*.nii` file. Any pointers related are most welcome.

Comment: ***I am currently having problems installing ITK package.*** Maybe you should give the details of that.

Answer (score 6):

You can install SimpleITK in Python and use it to do the conversion. For example,

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

root_path = '/path/to/image'
nii_path = root_path + '/data.nii'
mha_path = root_path + '/data.mha'

img = sitk.ReadImage(nii_path)
sitk.WriteImage(img, mha_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another route to solving this problem is installing sci-kit image and simpleitk.

This requires no building from source or wrapping of ITK and allows reading of MHA files and writing to NIFTI format.

```
pip install scikit-image 
pip install SimpleITK or easy_install -U SimpleITK
```

With these installed if you run the following code this should work

```
import skimage.io as io

path = 'C:/test.mha' #path to your MHA file
outpath = 'C:/test.nii'

img = io.imread(path,plugin='simpleitk')
io.imsave('outpath',img,plugin='simpleitk')
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an answer to this question I waste 24 hours, but at last, I could say it's so simple to convert from .mha to .nii file
1. first you have to install SimpleITK package in conda or which environment you are using

After that, just follow the below steps for conversion of any file.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

OUTPUT_DIR = 'Output'

# Image = sitk.ReadImage('lena1.png')
Image = sitk.ReadImage('Flair.mha')
print(Image.GetPixelIDTypeAsString())
sitk.WriteImage(Image, os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'Flair.nii'))
# sitk.WriteImage(Image, os.path.join(OUTPUT_DIR, 'SimpleITK.bmp'))
# plt.imshow(sitk.GetArrayViewFromImage(Image))
# plt.axis('off')
# plt.show()
```

by following these steps, i think you guys will get the required output.